# React js Navbar not showing result in browser and has no error occurred

Tags: reactjs

I want to run my Navbar.js by importing it to app.js, and app.js is imported to Index.js
This my Index.js

I expect to show Home page or History page when I enter url http://localhost:3000/ or http://localhost:3000/history

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This is my app.js(Only Hi from H1 element is showing)

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './pages/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App"> 
        
      <h1>Hi</h1>
      <Navbar />
       
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

This is my Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import History from './History';
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div>    
    
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/history" component={History} />
      </Routes>
    
    </div>
  )
}
export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using react-router-dom v5 or below, you need a `Switch` to display your route depending on the url. Here is [a repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pxsxgu?file=src%2FApp.js) and here is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/history">History</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Navbar />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;
const History = () => <div>History</div>;

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/history" component={History} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Since you are using React 18+ here is a basic routing example using react-router-dom 6.14 as well :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Outlet, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;
const History = () => <div>History</div>;


const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/history" element={<History />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'd like it to be separated files like Navbar.js export to App.js and App.js export to root.render Index.js. So can you help please?

Comment: That does not change anything, your exports are good, you just need to add the Switch component. I condensed all the code into one file so it's easier to paste here.